# Golang File reader scopes mistake

Tags: for-loop, go, initialization, scopes

I'm trying to understand difference between two file-reading cases.

Code below works fine. We reading file line-by-line to the variable:

```
reader := bufio.NewReader(file)

var line string
for err != io.EOF {
    line, err = reader.ReadString('\n')
    log.Println(line)
}
```

But if I want to init (using reader) in **for** scope reader will infinitely read only first line of code:

```
reader := bufio.NewReader(file)

var line string
for line, err = reader.ReadString('\n'); err != io.EOF; {
    log.Println(line)
}
```

Please, explain me why it happens? Thanks

Comment: because you're performing read only in initialization block (which is run only once). Move it to the post statement as well.
https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/1

Comment: Wow, really, thank you :)

Comment: Welcome. posted the same answer. You can close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move it from initialization (Which [runs only once](https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/1)) to post-statement.
Change it to

```
for line, err = reader.ReadString('\n'); err != io.EOF; line, err = reader.ReadString('\n') {
    log.Println(line)
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's not the best decision (we have repeated code) but I could see true difference. Thank you. It solves my problem